# python: globally reloading a module

Tags: python, python-import

I am making a pygame dialog and i have files that are like that:

window.py:

```
class Window():
    def set_size(self, size):
        self.size = size

main_window = Window()
```

dialogs.py:

```
from window import main_window
class Question():
    def __init__(self):
        # lots of initializing
        self.position = (main_window.size[0] / 2, main_window.size[1] / 2) # centering dialog

question = Question()
```

other files:

```
from window import main_window
from dialogs import question

# do something
```

The problem is that if i change the size of the main window in one of the other files, then the question dialog will no longer be centered, since question is already initialized with a different screen size. So, i want to make the set_size method reload the question module for all other files. How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you make the `position` a *property*, recalculated as required based on the *current* `main_window.size`? Reloading `window` won't help, as the attribute is already permanently set.

Comment: it could have been a property, it actually is a property in my original code, but it makes no difference. And i want to reload the `question` dialog to fix `self.position` not the `window`

Comment: Your model seems a bit broken. Why do you create the instances directly in their modules? Why not create a `Question` instance with an explicit reference to a `Window`; `question = Question(main_window)`?

Comment: well, i only need one window that's easily accessible by all modules. And i used one dialog to make the initialization code executed only once. It probably was a wrong choice, but i'd rather avoid changing everything now.